# JQuery check status of checkbox

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I am using the following code to check the status of a check box - I get back a 'Y' when enabled but returns undefined when it is disabled. How can ensure my JS does not throw and error and can detect the appropriate states at run time - ideally would like to have a Y or N answer to the selector.

Thanks

```
  var isRequested = $('input[name=componentId]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.is(':checked')`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
var isRequested = $('input[name=componentId]').is(':checked');//True||False
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
 var isRequested =$('input[name=componentId]').prop('checked')
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but neither of the above options are working for me - I am using JQuery from within a Prime Faces container could that be the issue ?